# How to disassociate angularFire bound object?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am using AngularJS and FireBase in my application. I bound an object to be in sync with FireBase:

```
$scope.winnerPromise = angularFire(travelBidsFirebaseRef + "/user/" + $scope.auction.winnerUserId, $scope, 'winner', {});
```

Now I want to disassociate $scope.winner, meaning I want it to stay safe in the FireBase DB, but I don't want my scope variable 'winner' to be synchronized with it anymore. How do I do that? I saw disassociate() finction in angularfire.js but I don't see how I can use it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disassociate function is passed to you when the promise is resolved. I'd use it as follows:

```js
var ref = travelBidsFirebaseRef.child("user/" + $scope.auction.winnerUserId);
var promise = angularFire(ref, $scope, "winner", {});
promise.then(function(disassociate) {
  // Do some work...
  disassociate(); // Don't synchronize $scope.winner anymore.
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It helped, thanks! It would be great to have the disassociate() function attached to the scope object, e.g. $scope.winner.disassociate(); since it's often not the case that all code is inside the promise.then() function. I actually tried to do so: $scope.winner.disassociate = disassociate; However, the bound scope object references (e.g. $scope.winner) are reassigned with a new object every time the object changes.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately due to the way changes to objects are observed by Angular, I don't recommend attaching functions to $scope objects that are bound to Firebase URLs. You may store the function under a seperate $scope variable though, like $scope.disassociateWinner()

Answer (score 0):

I am using angularfire and for me it worked the `$destroy` method.

https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#destroy-1