# How to correctly disassociate $firebase AngularJS binding?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Let the image do the talking: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jgdj8LBQRs [25 sec]

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/pL3z77vmYeSZzGMSL0YV?p=preview

Firebase GUI: http://syncing.firebase-demo.io/

I'm using angular 1.2.6 (fairly recent) and AngularFire 0.6 (latest).

### Steps to reproduce

- I have a list of todos that is syncing with Firebase
- I log in and local changes are propagated to Firebase
- I log out and I disassociate binding, clearing local scope
- I log in again: strange things happen (see [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jgdj8LBQRs))

Critical fragments of code below ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pL3z77vmYeSZzGMSL0YV?p=preview) has it all)

### 1. Controller

```
    $rootScope.$watch("loginState", function() {
        $scope.loginState = $rootScope.loginState;
        if ($scope.loginState == "loggedIn") {
            $scope.$firRef = $firebase(new Firebase($scope.firebaseURL + "testuser/todos/"));
            $scope.$firRef.$bind($scope, "todos").then(function(unbind) {
              $scope.unbindFunction = unbind; // I store reference to unbinding function
            });
        } else if ($scope.loginState == "loggedOut") {
            $scope.unbindFunction(); // and call it on logout
            $scope.$firRef = null // doesn't help either
            $scope.todos = [];
        }
    });

    $scope.login = function() {
        loginService.login();
    }        

    $scope.logout = function() {
        loginService.logout();
    }
```

*(note that I store reference to unbind function and call it on logout)*

### 2. Service

```
app.factory('loginService', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        login: function() {
            $rootScope.loginState = "loggedIn";
        },
        logout: function() {
            $rootScope.loginState = "loggedOut";
        }
    }
}]);
```

Docs about 3-way data binding: https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html#bind-scope-model

Related:

- [How to disassociate angularFire bound object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144812/how-to-disassociate-angularfire-bound-object)
- [Prevent items in scope from writing to a different user's records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482108/prevent-items-in-scope-from-writing-to-a-different-users-records)

### I would be very keen to know how to properly synchronise collections between logging-in and logging-out.

Comment: You may consider calling `$scope.firRef.$off()` as well. I think there might be a separate bug with the unbinding code, I'll take a look.

Comment: First impressions: ```$scope.firRef.$off()``` does the trick! Wish I knew that earlier... :)

Comment: Ok, the big problem here is that you are mixing data types - objects and arrays. In 'logged out' mode, you are using an array, but the regular representation is an object. Don't do this.

Comment: After switching to only use objects, there is still a bug with AngularFire's merge algorithm (i.e. merging changes you made while being 'logged out' along with the data that's already in Firebase). I filed an issue https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/issues/259 to track this.

Comment: Thank you @Anant for clarification, I've added my comment to github issue so I'm in the know. Regarding use of **arrays** and **objects** how would you recommend to solve it? ```if ($scope.$firRef != null) {              $scope.$firRef.$add($scope.newTodo); } else{ $scope.todos.push($scope.newTodo); }``` - Maybe ```$scope.arrayNotLoggedIn``` and  ```$scope.$firebaseLoggedIn``` ?

Comment: For anyone reading this nowadays, it seems the correct function name is off() - i.e. no `$` - correct me if I'm wrong though...