# How to correctly synchronise collection using Angular Firebase 3-way data bindings?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm using Angular, Firebase and 3-way data bindings.

I'm also using **filter**, so the items active *(state 1)* are listed on the top, items paused *(state 2)* are listed on the bottom. Of course this is just an example use of filtering:

`<todo ng-repeat="item in todos | orderByPriority | filter: {state: 1}"></todo>`

It seems to have strange consequences when using 3-way bindings with Angular and Firebase.

#### 1. When new item is added to collection, all other items on temporarily disappear. Why?

- http://plnkr.co/edit/aamS7aX5Oun4hCuoDqf5?p=preview
- http://youtu.be/YauwP5Qw4vA
- Essential bits of code below:

  ```
  $scope.firebaseURL = "https://flickering-date.firebaseio-demo.com/";
  $scope.todos = [
      {name: 'post to stack overflow', state: 1, dateAdded : new Date(2013,1,1)}, 
      {name: 'plunker', state: 2, dateAdded : new Date(2013,2,2)},
      {name: 'github', state: 3, dateAdded : new Date(2013,3,3)},
      {name: 'mailing list', state: 1, dateAdded : new Date(2013,4,4)}
  ];
  $scope.state = 1;

  $scope.$firRef = $firebase(new Firebase($scope.firebaseURL + "todos/"));
  $scope.$firRef.$bind($scope, "todos").then(function(unbind) {
    $scope.unbindFunctionUnused = unbind;
  });
  ```

Linking function in directive:

```
            var intervalId = $interval(function() {
                var squared = scope.item.counter * scope.item.counter;
                element.find(".squared").html(squared);
                scope.item.counter++;
            }, 1000);
```

Initially I was thinking it has something to do with Date object but similar strange behaviour occurs for integers too. (see below)

#### 2. Populating square of a number work OK for local array. For array synced with Firebase no value is displayed (it flickers occassionally).

- http://plnkr.co/edit/UGlk3Yhohs4GHyvHU7BO?p=preview
- http://youtu.be/6iLOYc14XRY
- Essential code below

  ```
  $scope.firebaseURL = "https://flickering-counter.firebaseio-demo.com/";
  $scope.todosFirebase = [
      {name: 'plunker firebase', counter : 11, state: 1 },
      {name: 'github firebase', counter: 22, state: 2},
      {name: 'stack overflow firebase', counter: 33, state: 3}
  ];
  $scope.todos = [
      {name: 'plunker', counter : 11, state: 1 },
      {name: 'github', counter: 22, state: 2},
      {name: 'stack overflow', counter: 33, state: 3}
  ];
  $scope.state = 1;

  $scope.$firRef = $firebase(new Firebase($scope.firebaseURL + "todos/"));
  $scope.$firRef.$bind($scope, "todosFirebase").then(function(unbind) {
    $scope.unbindFunctionUnused = unbind;
  });

  $scope.addItem = function() { // note that we add to both instances
      $scope.todosFirebase.$add({name: $scope.newItem, state: $scope.state, counter: 0});
      $scope.todos.push({name: $scope.newItem, state: $scope.state, counter: 0});
  }
  ```

  Linking function in directive:

  ```
          var intervalId = $interval(function() {

              var added = new Date(scope.item.dateAdded).getTime();
              var now = new Date().getTime();
              var diff = new Date(now - added);

              element.find(".timeelapsed").html(diff.toString());
          }, 1000);
  ```

---

Yesterday I asked related question - [How to correctly disassociate $firebase AngularJS binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21963735/how-to-correctly-disassociate-firebase-angularjs-binding) - it also touches Firebase, Angular and 3-way data binding. Today I wanted to investigate further but I'm kind of stuck...

What I want to do:

- I add an item to the list
- It has a counter
- It refreshes every 1 sec
- It just works

*(for some reason I cannot make it work in my setup)*

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I actually wanted to downvote myself for this question :]

The solution is embarrassingly simple:

```
var _updateFunction = function() {
    var squared = scope.item.counter * scope.item.counter;
    element.find(".squared").html(squared); 
    scope.item.counter++;
}

var intervalId = $interval(_updateFunction, 1000);

_updateFunction(); // <-- cpt Obvious
```

Related: [Execute the setInterval function without delay the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685396/execute-the-first-time-the-setinterval-without-delay)